# Where to keep simple counter value (except DB and File)

Tags: php

I have a counter which I increment every page visit.  I do not want to keep this value in DB or in plain file.  Is there any other approach to keep it?

I need keep it for next visit. In the next visit I want to read it, increase and keep again.

Why I do not want to use DB?  Because in whole project I'm not using DB it's simple project.

Plain file it's maybe the easiest solution. And every concurrency access can be solved by PHP.
But maybe is there anything easier and lightweight than plain file (in performance sense ?

Comment: Memcached, APC, Redis and friends. They're all super-easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use database, next easy way is - as you wrote - use single file like

```
counter.txt
```

which will contains only an integer value.

Then open file, read value, increase, write, close. It will be quite fast operation.

That solution was used before databases became popular.

Comment: but this solution can't be fast. I thought maybe start using memcache ? and dump it every hour to file :) ?

Comment: it is reasonable fast - don't forget that for example your PHP scripts are textfiles, too. If you don't need your counter permanently and just for one client, you could use session or cookies, too. Otherwise you need some kind of persistance, file, db, or some fancy cloud storage